# The asset "rails_admin/rails_admin.css" is not present in the asset pipeline. ):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-admin

I am using rails admin. My application is working perfectly in local but when its throwing the above error while configuring in live

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.css *.js ckeditor/*)
```

But when I precompile my assets, nothing is compiled.

Comment: have you enabled config.assets.compile = true in production.rb

Comment: Yes, I have enabled it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Possible Solution

1. install yarn
2. install webpacker by running

   ```
   RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails webpacker:install
   ```
3. production.rb

   ```
   config.assets.compile = true
   ```
4. Now precompile your assets

   ```
   RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
   ```

Comment: webpacker is installed by default in Rails 6.0 and up

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add to config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( rails_admin/rails_admin.css 
rails_admin/rails_admin.js )
```

And if you are deploying to Heroku, you can check their assets troubleshooting: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#rails-asset-pipeline

Or if you are not deploying to Heroku

```
npm -g i yarn
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompil
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true bundle exec rails s -e production
```

Comment: Even I tried it before, but my assets are not precompiled

Comment: @honey how did you check if they are not precompiled? Doesn't assets:precompile create the `public/assets/rails_admin` for you?

Comment: to test production environment locally without heroku run this `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true bundle  exec rails s -e production` after assets:precompile step